# How to Authorize Azure Devops using c# API?

Tags: c#, post, https, azure-devops

I have installed "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" package in VS and creating DevOps Work item forms. I want to add custom Rules to the work item form using below code. When running below code I am getting the 'result' value as html content

output:    "Azure DevOps Services | Sign In"

```
Code:
     var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/work/processes/processid/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Epic/rules?api-version=6.0-preview.2");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";            
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = @"{ 
                                'name': 'customRule',
                              'conditions': [
                                {
                                  'conditionType': '$when',
                                  'field': 'Custom.parentdrpdwn',
                                  'value': 'value1'
                                }
    
                              ],
                              'actions': [
                                {
                                  'actionType': '$setDefaultValue',
                                  'targetField': 'Custom.childrpdwn',
                                  'value': 'value2'
                                }
                              ],
                              'isDisabled': false
                        }";
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }
    
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

because of this authentication issue I am not able to post the https request ,how can we authorize the Azure DevOps in the same method and create custom business rule in my Org ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to [create PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) in the web page and then use it in the code. Here is an sample.

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalAccessToken)));
```

We could refer to the doc [Get started sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=azure-devops) and [Get started with the REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps API uses basic auth. You just need to add a header:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
string patEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + patEncoded);
```

You can use your username + password or generate a personal access token (PAT). For a PAT, leave the username empty.